# How to correctly catch Axios ECONNRESET?

Tags: node.js, axios

Here's my routine that call a remote endpoint:

```
static getOrder = async (apiEndpoint, orderId, instrument) => {
    return await new Promise((next, fail) => {
        axios({
            method: 'get',
            url: apiEndpoint,
            headers: {
                'X-MBX-APIKEY': apiKey,
            }
        }).then(function (response) {
            // some op

            next(data);
        }).catch(function (error) {
            fail(Helpers.handleAxiosError(error, "getOrder " + orderId));
        });
    });
}
```

I'd like to catch the `econnreset` error accurately, in a way that will just warning it silently.

What's the correct way of doing this? On which variable/statuscode should I'm looking for?

i.e. understand that's an `Axios` error and its `econnreset`?

Comment: You can verify `error.code`, it will be `ECONNRESET` in your case.

Comment: @hoangdv but how can I discrimate its Axios error? "code" its too generic as field...

Comment: `error` will be an instance of `AxiosError` (from `axios`)